# Stop AUCTeX asking how much space I want to insert between rows in tables

Tags: latex, auctex

I'd like to avoid being asked how much vertical space I want to insert at the end of a row in tables and have `C-c C-j` behave like `C-u C-c C-j`.

Comment: @ArashEsbati thanks for the suggestion. I've read [AUCTeX's manual page about completion](https://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/manual/auctex/Completion.html) and found something interesting, but I still wonder if I can have I finer-grained control over functions that ask for optional argument, that is, stop only `LaTeX-item-tabular*` from doing it.

Comment: I'm settling with `(setq TeX-insert-macro-default-style 'mandatory-args-only)` and `LaTeX-default-position nil` but I'm still open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've already mentioned in your comment, you can disable query for optional arguments during completion globally with:

```lisp
(setq TeX-insert-macro-default-style 'mandatory-args-only)
```

For your special use case and since you want to redefine an AUCTeX function, I suggest another approach: Write an AUCTeX style file which does the redefinition of two responsible functions like this:

```lisp
;;; tab-no-opt.el --- AUCTeX style for redefining 2 AUCTeX core functions

(defun LaTeX-item-array (&optional suppress)
  "Insert line break macro on the last line and suitable number of &'s.
For array and tabular environments.  Temporarily bind
`TeX-insert-macro-default-style' to mandatory-args-only when
inserting \"\\\\\".

If SUPPRESS is non-nil, do not insert line break macro."
  (unless suppress
    (save-excursion
      (end-of-line 0)
      (just-one-space)
      (let ((TeX-insert-macro-default-style 'mandatory-args-only))
        (TeX-insert-macro "\\"))))
  (LaTeX-insert-ampersands
   LaTeX-array-skipping-regexp 'LaTeX-array-count-columns))

(defun LaTeX-item-tabular* (&optional suppress)
  "Insert line break macro on the last line and suitable number of &'s.
For tabular* environment only.  Temporarily bind
`TeX-insert-macro-default-style' to mandatory-args-only when
inserting \"\\\\\".

If SUPPRESS is non-nil, do not insert line break macro."
  (unless suppress
    (save-excursion
      (end-of-line 0)
      (just-one-space)
      (let ((TeX-insert-macro-default-style 'mandatory-args-only))
        (TeX-insert-macro "\\"))))
  (LaTeX-insert-ampersands
   LaTeX-tabular*-skipping-regexp 'LaTeX-array-count-columns))

;;; tab-no-opt.el ends here
```

The only change is that the variable `TeX-insert-macro-default-style` is temporarily `let`-bound to the symbol `mandatory-args-only` for inserting the control symbol `\\`.

Set the variable `TeX-auto-private` to a directory of your choice, save the code above as `tab-no-opt.el` there and restart Emacs.

Next, write a dummy LaTeX package `tab-no-opt.sty` like this and save it your `texmf-local` directory where LaTeX can find it:

```latex
\ProvidesPackage{tab-no-opt}
  [2017/05/25 v0.0 Dummy package for AUCTeX redefinitions]
\relax
\endinput
```

Finally, in the preamble of your working .tex file, do <kbd>C-c C-m usepackage RET tab-no-opt RET</kbd> and AUCTeX should load the style file above and you should be done.  I recommend you put this line in your init file

```lisp
(setq TeX-parse-self t)
```

if you want AUCTeX to load the style each time you open your .tex file.  You should now be able to compile your file and get the desired result within Emacs.

Comment: I didn't think it was so complicated, thanks for the effort!